# Handling photon momenta | addition subtraction

Tags: particle-physics, photons, momentum

My problem relates to the decay of a neutral pion, more precisely the decay into two photons.

If the pion the rests the momenta of the two photons are contrarily.
If the pion still has some momentum at its decay it will be transferred to the photons. (EDIT: The momenta given by the rest enrgy of the pion will always be contrarily. In case the pion is still moving there will be some extra momentum and the photons will most likely not move in opposite directins)

If the photons appear under a certain angle to the pion's direction I can calculate the photons momenta with simple geometry.
But what happens if one photon appears in the same direction as the pion and the other one in the opposite direction. If the pion has a mass of 135MeV/c^2 and a momentum of 135MeV/c the photons share them in equal parts (!?). In case of the back photon the momenta would cancel out thus having no momentum.

How do I handle this scenario?

Postscript:
(The superscripted numbers are indizes not exponents)
Given a pion with mass $m_\pi$ and momentum $\vec{p_\pi}$.
The decay will create two photons $\gamma_1$,$\gamma_2$ that share equal parts of $m_\pi$ (follows from conservation of momentum CoM)

$$E_{\pi_{rest}}=m_\pi c^2 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad E_\gamma=\frac{E_{\pi_{rest}}}{2}$$
$$\left|\vec{p^1_\gamma}\right|=\frac{E_\gamma}{c}=\frac{m_\pi c}{2} \quad (1)$$

CoM leads to

$$\vec{p^1_{\gamma_1}}=-\vec{p^1_{\gamma_2}} \quad (2)$$

$p_\pi$ will be devided onto both photons (Assume the parts are equal)

$$\vec{p^2_{\gamma_1}}=\vec{p^2_{\gamma_2}}=\frac{\vec{p_{\pi}}}{2} \quad (3)$$

Thus:

$$\vec{p_{\gamma_1}}=\vec{p^1_{\gamma_1}}+\vec{p^2_{\gamma_1}} \\
\vec{p_{\gamma_2}}=\vec{p^1_{\gamma_2}}+\vec{p^2_{\gamma_2}}$$

If now $m_\pi c=\left|\vec{p_\pi}\right| \quad $ and $ \quad \vec{p^1_\gamma} \parallel \vec{p_\pi}$ using (1),(2) and (3)

$$\vec{p_{\gamma_1}}=\frac{\vec{p_{\pi}}}{2}+\frac{\vec{p_{\pi}}}{2}=\vec{p_{\pi}} \\
\vec{p_{\gamma_2}}=\frac{\vec{p_{\pi}}}{2}-\frac{\vec{p_{\pi}}}{2}=0$$

The total momentum is still $p_\pi$ but the second photon has no momentum.
How do I interpret this? Is there only one photon or is $p_\pi$ devided unequal?

Comment: If the photons are going in opposite directions, then the total momentum *must* zero which means the pion was at rest & thus contradicts your assertion it was moving, no?

Comment: That was meant in the rest system of the pion. In the labor they won't be opposite.

Comment: Right, they won't be opposite in the lab frame. So what's the question then?

Comment: It is possible that one of the photons will appear in the same direction the pion was moving. The other one has to travel in the opposite direction. They will have different momenta.

Comment: Wouldn't that contradict conservation laws?

Comment: How?  The total momentum of both photons should be the one from the pion. The additional momenta come from the mass of the pion that decays. So the mass is devided in equal parts to both photons and the pion's momentum will be devided and added somehow. The momentum of a photon is variable, given by its energy

Comment: Well have you tried working the math of it? If not, what's stopping you?

Comment: I added a postscriptum

Comment: The photons only have equal energy in the pion rest frame. If you do a Lorentz transform to a frame in which the pion is moving, then the two photos do not have the same energy because they are moving in different directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a pion at rest decaying. Then move your frame in the direction of one of the photons. In this frame the energy and momenta of the photons are different. The error is in assuming the energy is equally divided, but it is true only in the rest frame of the pion.

Comment: So $\vec{p^1_{\gamma_1}}=-\vec{p^1_{\gamma_2}}$ is incorrect in the lab frame?

Comment: Yes, incorrect. The correct identity is that the vector sum of the photon momenta equals the pion momentum. So if the photons are in the direction of the pion movement, then their momenta is different by the value of the pion momentum.

Comment: Thank you very much. Apparently my reputation is to low to give you credit by upvoting.